# How to share an image publicly in Azure without opening myself to b/w abuse/costs

Tags: azure

I've (think I've) thought through every way I can think of sharing an image in Azure and they all leave me open to someone abusing the download and costing me in bandwidth costs.

The goal is an AMI-like experience, except that seems right out, so settle for a solution that forces the user to copy the image to their subscription first, then create a Shared Image Gallery from that. But again, without exposing a raw download to the Internet, or allowing cross-region intra-Azure pulls that would also cost money.

- public blob in Azure StorageV2 account- exposes you to bw attack
- public blob in Azure StorageV2 account with Firewall - Microsoft Trusted Services that are default allowed doesn't seem to include the image service, though I didn't test this myself. If it *did* this might work, as the Image service blocks cross-location replication from blob storage by default IIRC.
- Shared Image Gallery - cross tenant sharing is clunky, not at all feasible for AMI-like scenarios
- ???

I do not want to go through the process of being a Marketplace certified image, which as far as I can tell, is the only publicly available route for making a truly public image and not incurring costs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Perhaps you can add code and specific details? Not sure what you mean by "shared image gallery." Also, I don't know why you're thinking you have exposure to bandwidth costs. And I'm unsure what you're talking about regarding a "marketplace certified image" - what does that mean? Are these graphic images? VMs? As for your code and app: How are you hosting your images? Blob storage? Are you using Shared Access Signatures? Please edit to include details. Otherwise I suspect this question will be closed as unclear (plus, not a programming question).

Comment: All of these things are very clear to anyone who reads the post and gets Azure as the context. I'll edit it to be more explicit, but if you enumerate all of the ways to publish a VM Image in Azure, and look at my post, it's quite obvious what I'm referring to?

Comment: Shared Image Gallery is a top-level Azure product...

Comment: Marketplace VM Images is the only way to publish an image publicly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/marketplace-virtual-machines  and I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: Sharing a blob of a disk image publicly is referred to all over the Internet as the way to share images. That exposes you to download abuses. Someone can sit there and download the image over and over and cost me Azure Storage network egress costs.

Comment: I have no problem with Azure concepts - I'm extremely familiar with it, since I've been working with it since its inception, and it's my day job. However, I parsed your question originally as "image gallery" being... graphic images as part of an app, not as a VM image (meaning it's not "very clear" to someone experience in Azure). Note that deploying VM images isn't really a topic for Stack Overflow, as it's not programming-related (I had assumed it was, when reading, hence the confusion). Maybe better to ask on ServerFault, since there's no programming question here...

Comment: Also it might be best to contact the folks responsible for the marketplace, to get a better idea of specific policies around image-hosting and related costs.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put it in a storage account and user Shared Access Signatures?

Then its still possible to download over internet if you have the SAS, its easy to withdraw the SAS and you can limit it both in time and by IP if needed.

[image]

Comment: FYI you cannot withdraw or invalidate a Shared Access Signature prior to its expiration date (you'd have to delete the source blob, or regenerate the storage account's key). You can only manage Shared Access *Policies*.

Comment: @DavidMakogon You regenerate they key the SAS is based on and then it won’t work anymore.

Comment: Right - that key is either the primary or secondary account key. Regenerating that key is what I mentioned above. And regenerating that key impacts *all* SAS keys based on it, as well as any other storage access based on that key; there is no fine-grained way to decommission a single SAS without having a larger impact.